# TSQL Date range for this week and next week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am working on a query where I need to provide a total number of meetings that fall in the date range of the current week as well as the number that falls in the range of next week.

A week for us is considered Monday - Sunday. In the code below, I have it outputting the correct dates but I feel there is a much cleaner and productive way to accomplish this.

Can anyone shed some light on alternatives to my query below that will provide me with the same outcomes?

```
DECLARE @TodayDayOfWeek INT
DECLARE @StartOfWeek DATETIME
DECLARE @EndOfWeek DATETIME
DECLARE @StartNextWeek DATETIME
DECLARE @EndNextWeek DATETIME
SET DATEFIRST 1; 


SET @TodayDayOfWeek = datepart(dw, GetDate())
SET @StartOfWeek = DATEADD(dd, -(@TodayDayOfWeek-1), GetDate())
SET @EndOfWeek = DATEADD(dd, -(@TodayDayOfWeek-7), GetDate())
SET @StartNextWeek = DATEADD(dd, -(@TodayDayOfWeek-8), GetDate())
SET @EndNextWeek = DATEADD(dd, -(@TodayDayOfWeek-14), GetDate())

SELECT @StartOfWeek
SELECT @EndOfWeek
SELECT @StartNextWeek
SELECT @EndNextWeek
```

Comment: This is a common method to get the First day of the week. I don't think it's necessarily cleaner than what you'r already doing, but it's worth sharing.

SELECT DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK,0,GETDATE()),0)

Comment: @samyi scalar functions are notoriously poor performers and there is certainly no need for one here.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you make your queries non-sargable by running these in the where clause but if you're doing this repeatedly... why wouldn't you wrap it in a function. Also, wrapping it in a properly named function makes the code more readable as well. It's not necessarily that the functions are poor performing... you just have to be more selective. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

SQL lets you choose the week number with DATEPART. Their definition of a week starts with monday and ends with sunday so the same as yours. You can use a where clause to sort out which dates you want or group by week and count the meetings in each week etc...

```
    DECLARE @yourMeetings TABLE (MeetingDates DATE);

INSERT INTO @yourMeetings
VALUES  (GETDATE()),
        (DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())),
        (DATEADD(DAY,2,GETDATE())),
        (DATEADD(DAY,3,GETDATE())),
        (DATEADD(DAY,4,GETDATE())),
        (DATEADD(DAY,5,GETDATE())),
        (DATEADD(DAY,6,GETDATE())),
        (DATEADD(DAY,7,GETDATE()));


SELECT *,
        DATEPART(wk,MeetingDates) AS Week_Num,
        DATENAME(WEEKDAY,MeetingDates) AS Day_Name
        /*COUNT(MeetingDates)*/
FROM @yourMeetings
--WHERE DATEPART(wk,MeetingDates) = 12;

/*GROUP BY DATEPART(wk,MeetingDates)*/
```

Results(Today is March 19):

```
MeetingDates Week_Num    Day_Name
------------ ----------- ------------------------------
2015-03-19   12          Thursday
2015-03-20   12          Friday
2015-03-21   12          Saturday
2015-03-22   12          Sunday
2015-03-23   13          Monday
2015-03-24   13          Tuesday
2015-03-25   13          Wednesday
2015-03-26   13          Thursday
```